# Using trace with functions not defined by me

Tags: common-lisp, trace, sbcl

I'm using sbcl 1.4.6 and I have this behaviour:

```
*  (trace string<)

(STRING<)
*  (string< "hola" "pato")
  0: (STRING< "hola" "pato")
  0: STRING< returned 0
0
*  (defun test-without-cond (str)
           (string< "hola" str))

TEST-WITHOUT-COND
* (test-without-cond "pato")

0
```

If the function is allready defined in common lisp, I cannot use trace when using inside a user defined function. BUt this is not a problem if I define the function

```
* (defun my-string< (str) (string< str "hello"))
MY-STRING<

* (trace my-string<)

(MY-STRING<)

* (defun test-2 (str) (my-string< str))

TEST-2
* (test-2 "gato")
  0: (MY-STRING< "gato")
  0: MY-STRING< returned 0
0
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: This is a standard function, for which the following applies: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_abab.htm  You may want to shadow string< with another symbol which wraps the standard function. Shadowing allows you to change the meaning without having to edit your sources. You need however to reread all impacted forms and recompile/reevaluate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What can be traced depends on the implementation and various settings.

For SBCL read the manual: [Open Coding and Inline Expansion](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Open-Coding-and-Inline-Expansion)

But SBCL now also has an interpreter and it looks like you can trace calls to CL functions from interpreted code:

```
* (setf  *evaluator-mode* :interpret)

:INTERPRET
* (trace string<)

(STRING<)
* (defun test-without-cond (str)
    (string< "hola" str))

TEST-WITHOUT-COND
* (test-without-cond "pato")
  0: (STRING< "hola" "pato")
  0: STRING< returned 0
0
*
```

Note that one might need to be careful with tracing core functions, since they can be called a lot...